# Tick event, direct use

Tags: c#, events, handler

I want to do some code every tick.

```
timer.Tick += new EventHandler(TabPage tab = new TabPage(Convert.ToString("test"));)
```

But this is wrong, I don't remember how do this correctly.

I do not want to call any other class/void, I want do some code directly in EventHandler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "[EventHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler.aspx)" is a function [delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).  The Tick event is expecting you to assign a function name which conforms to a certain signature.  You can assign a new event handler in two ways:

Pass an actual function, which matches the signature:

```
timer.Tick += new EventHandler(MyEventHandler); //This function will be executed every tick

//Somewhere below...
private void MyEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    //Do stuff here
}
```

Or, use an anonymous delegate or [lambda function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) right in the same place as the EventHandler assignment.

```
timer.Tick += new EventHandler((obj, args) =>
{
    /* Code here */
});
```

Comment: Glad I could help.  Don't forget to mark the correct answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this using [Lambda](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx).

```
timer.Tick += new EventHandler((sender, args) => 
    {
        /* Your code */
    });
```